# Markers move when zooming with Google Maps Android API v2

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

When adding some markers on a map using Google Maps Android API v2, the markers are no set to the right positions and move when zooming.

When zooming in they get closer to the right positions, as if they were translated by a factor related to the zoom.

What's wrong?

Example zooming in:

[image]
[image]
[image]

**fragment**

```
public class CenterMapFragment extends Fragment {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private List<Center> mCenterList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.center_map_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState); 

        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();

        if (mMap != null) {

            mCenterList = MyApplication.dbHelper.getAllCenter();

            for(Center center : mCenterList){

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(center.lat, center.lng)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .fromResource(R.drawable.myicon)));

            }
        }

    }

}
```

**layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Now as you added screenshots I can say that problem is definately in anchors

Comment: Are there any white space on your icon?

Comment: same problem any solution?

Comment: @UsmanGhauri Yes, the accepted one.

Comment: @jul : doesn't work for me. i tried adding anchor it still locate to slightly off. i hit and trial these but still no luck. im using an svg icon for location pin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For custom markers you need also use

`MarkerOptions.anchor(float u, float v)`

which describes where is the pointer point on the marker. By default this point is located at middle-bottom of the image.

Comment: BitmapDescriptor has no method anchor. It's a MarkerOptions and is: "The point on the image that will be placed at the LatLng position of the marker. This defaults to the middle of the bottom of the image.". It shouldn't modify the position.

Comment: @jul sorry, indeed - this is a method of the `MarkerOptions`. Anyway, this is what you are looking for. "It shouldn't modify the position" - means that location of the image won't affect actual lattitude and longitude on the map. It just translates image on u*100 percents to the right and on v*100 percents to the top.

Comment: @jul also, it maybe somewhat helpful if you'll provide screenshot of your problem.

Comment: I added the pictures. I just tried with default marker and it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

To show an window info, you have to use setInfoWindowAdapter on your "mMap" or have a title set for your marker.

About the icon, it seems to be moving when you zoom out, but the anchor always point to the same place on the map. You can set an anchor if the image you're using don't follow Google's icon pattern (anchor on the middle of the botton of the image). For that you have to do use [MarkerOptions' method anchor(u,v)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions?hl=pt-PT#anchor%28float,%20float%29)

Comment: As @jul mentioned - `anchor` is a method of `MarkerOptions`. I just forgot it )